# LinkedList Input via Scanner

Tags: java, linked-list, java.util.scanner

I'd appreciate any help, not sure if I understand this piece of code correctly.

So I use Scanner to fill in data for every Node in my list. I use `int N = in.nextInt()` to give my list a size. Let's say `N == 2`.

How does this code works actually? I tried to draw it, google, but still not sure if I understand it correctly.

```
public static Node readList(Scanner in) {
    int N = in.nextInt();
    Node head = new Node(-1);
    Node node = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node.next = new Node(in.nextInt());
        node = node.next;
    }
    return head.next;
}
```

So I was thinking:

`Node head = -1`; Another `Node node = head` (not sure why do we need it).

Than the loop  `I < N` (which is 2, for instance), so 2 times there will be an input from keyboard.

An input will go to the next (meaning it is a link to the next one), and then `Node node` will be overwritten, and instead of **-1** it is **5** (for instance, it it the 1st input).

Now we have Node `node = 2`. Next input is **10** so it it again next. We have `node = 2; node.next = 10`. Does it make any sense or my logic is incorrect?

I'm confused with what goes next? how do we return `head.next` (meaning what it the value of it)?

Comment: "I tried to draw it" Please show your picture. "In the comment below I'll write down what I think it is." No, [edit] your question. You can't format text in comments as well as in the question, which makes it hard to read.

Comment: "*`Node node = head` (not sure why do we need it).*" `head` is variable which will contain first node which should be returned from method. Later in your code you are using `node` to hold "currently" processed node (last one). If you would work only on `head` then you would lost reference to first node.

Comment: But that first node (head) IMO shouldn't only contain `-1`, instead it should contain first data and return should return `head` not `head.next`. I don't know where did you get that code from but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: I believe that ``head -1`` is created so the 1st input becomes the **head**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one : Read the size of the list (N)

Step two : Create the head of the list (the variable head)

Step three: Create a node variable that will hold the currently processed node of the list and make it equal to head (because the current node is the head one)

Now do a loop that does N iterations and on each iteration do:

Loop 1) Create a new node with the line `new Node(in.nextInt());` and initialize it from scanner.

Loop 2) node is the current  position of the list. Use that new node in loop 1) as next in the list with the assignment `node.next = new Node(in.nextInt());`

Loop 3) the current node is now the next one created in the previous steps (last one in the linked list)  `node = node.next;`

Repeat...

You can rewrite the loop like that if it is easier to understand it:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //use n instead of N because of java conventions
        int input=in.nextInt();
        Node theNewLastNodeInTheList = new Node(input);
        currentNode.next = theNewLastNodeInTheList;
        currentNode = theNewLastNodeInTheList;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation @Veselin Davidov

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see how the class `Node`  looks like:

```
public class Node {
    private int value;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

So for your code, first the node `head` is create which contains a value -1. Then for every value from 0 to N, a new Node will be created and put as the next node of the current node. Then the current node will be set to this next node so the next node of this node can be set.

Let's say the input is 5 and 10, we will have three nodes: the `head` node with value -1. The `next` value of the head node is a node with value 5 and the `next` value of that node is the node with value 10.

The return value of the method is the node created after the `head` node, so you'll never know the existence of the `head` node. You'll just be able to access the nodes starting from the one right after the head.

Maybe look at this: [Stacks and queues](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack)

Comment: "The return value of the method is the node created after the head node"
DAMN I finally got it! Appreciate! :)